# How do I determine how many windows with overlap fit into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-image

The `view_as_image` function of `skimage` returns windows of `numpy` arrays of predetermined size. For example, `view_as_windows(array, (20, 96), 5)` will return arrays windows of (20, 96) of the original array, sliding 5 rows at a time (if the width of the original array is also 96). **I need to determine in advance how many windows will be output by `skimage`.**

Say I have this array:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

array = np.random.randint(0, 255, (128, 96))
```

And I get windows of (20, 96), with a stride of 5.

```
view_as_windows(array, (20, 96), 5)
```

It will yield 22 windows. Like this:

```
first: (0:20, :)
second: (5:25, :)
third: (10:30, :)
```

How can I do this, i.e. get the number of windows it will create?

Comment: You just want the count of windows, i.e. 22?

Comment: yes just that. edited it for clarity

Comment: If you just need the count, you can simply do `len(view_as_windows(array, (20, 96), 5))`. `view_as_winodws` would simply be a view, hence no memory overhead, if that's bothering you.